# From Multiple Kotlin Coroutines suspended function to a single synchronous function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So, I have multiple `suspended` functions that looks like this

```
suspend fun getLatestCampaign(): List<Campaign> {
   return listOf()
}

suspend fun getRecommendedCampaign(): List<Campaign> {
   return listOf()
}
```

Since I want to run these function asynchronously, so I did it like this

```
val recommendedCampaignAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) { getRecommendedCampaign() }
val latestCampaignAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) { getLatestCampaign() }
```

And I also have function that will process the result of these async operations

```
fun displayCampaigns(campaigns: List<Campaign>) {}
```

What should I do, if I want every time one of these async operation complete, I want to call `displayCampaigns` and make sure `displayCampaigns` is executed synchronously.
So I don't want to wait both of these async operation to complete and then call `displayCampaigns`

Comment: just for logging, how about to call `displayCampaings()` in each async block before return.

Comment: Isn't it causing race condition. let say the async operation complete at the same time and they will execute `displayCampaings` also at the same time. am i right?

Comment: `getLatestCampaign()` and `getRecommendedCampaign()` can be normal functions. `suspend` is not needed in this context.

Answer (score 1):

1. `async` is not the tool for your job because you want to consume the result synchronously.
2. `Dispatchers.IO` is not the one you should use because you call suspendable functions (which I'll assume are non-blocking, otherwise they shouldn't be declared as suspendable).

What you want is the simplest case: `launch` two coroutines in the `Main` dispatcher, which should already have been set up as the default one:

```
class YourGuiClass : WhateverYourFrameworkWantsYouToExtend, CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = Job() + Dispatchers.Main

    fun refreshCampaigns() {
        launch {
            displayCampaigns(getRecommendedCampaign())
        }
        launch {
            displayCampaigns(getLatestCampaign())
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe if this `displayCampaigns` will mutate a shared state?

Comment: Since you're launching it on the main (GUI) thread, there's no multithreading involved. However, you should still be careful not to leave the shared state half-updated when hitting a suspension point.

Comment: Sorry that i didn't give more context, the reason why i use `suspend` for the `getRecommendedCampaigns` and `getLatestCampaigns` because it is a retrofit (network operation) functions so it's a blocking functions. that's why I make it async with Dispatchers.IO.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. If you plan on using plain-old blocking functions, then don't declare them `suspend`. In fact, don't use coroutines at all in that case since they don't bring you any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Either call `displayCampaigns` inside of the `async` blocks

```
val recommendedCampaignAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val campaigns = getRecommendedCampaign()
    displayCampaigns(campaigns)
}

val latestCampaignAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val campaigns = getLatestCampaign()
    displayCampaigns(campaigns)
}
```

or add a `CompletionHandler` to the jobs returned by async

```
recommendedCampaignAsync.invokeOnCompletion{
    displayCampaigns(recommendedCampaignAsync.getCompleted())
}

latestCampaignAsync.invokeOnCompletion{
    displayCampaigns(latestCampaignAsync.getCompleted())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Is there possibility where I'll run on race condition with `displayCampaigns`? let say these async operations is complete at the same time.

Comment: Yes `displayCampaigns` can be called by two threads at the "same" time. So you have to make sure this function is thread safe.